# How to configure inorder to commit some of the already commited files to another git repository in Android studio

Tags: git, android-studio, gitlab

I'm new to Git. I have installed git.exe on my computer and configured it initially in Android studio. I created a git repository (say GitRepo1) locally and I've committed all the files so far written. Now, I've created another repository locally.However, I want to abandon the previously created repository and I want to configure all of the files which have been committed to the old repository(gitrepo1) into the new repository (gitrepo2)and I want to configure the same to remote repository.I tried commit and pushing the files , but it would only identify the files that are changed recently and does not accept the old files which are already committed. Please help me in this regard.How to make the files unversioned and start versioning again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to replace all the items in the remote with the *gitrepo2* files?
If so, you need to commit all the files in the new project (gitrepo2) and force push into the old remote by executing:

```
git push -f
```

This will remove the previous history in the remote with the local one. But I'm not sure this is what you want to do.

On the other hand, if you want to remove your whole local history, you can simply remove the `.git` directory and then start a new repository by running (inside your project folder):

```
rm -r .git/
git init
git remote add origin remote-url-here
```

And start doing your new commits.

But I'm not sure neither of these options are what you intend to do. Please provide more information about your problem to help you out.

Comment: I needed the second solution, i.e remove the .git from local directory and start add the remote all the way again. :)